# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method Pasien::model()

Tags: php, codeigniter

What's wrong with my code

view pasien -> index.php

```
  <?php foreach ($data['psn'] as $psn ) : ?>
    <tr>
      <th ><?= $psn['id_pasien']; ?></th>
      <td><?= $psn['nama_pasien']; ?></td>
      <td><?= $psn['umur_pasien']; ?></td>
      <td><?= $psn['keterangan']; ?></td>
      <td class="text-primary"><?= $psn['keterangan']; ?></td>
    </tr>
  <?php endforeach; ?>
```

controllers -> Pasien.php

```
<?php

class Pasien extends Controller {
  public function index()
  {
    $data['judul'] = 'Data Pasien';
    $this->view('templates/header', $data);
    $this->view('pasien/index');
    $data['psn'] = $this->model('Data_pasien')->getPasien();
    $this->view('templates/footer');
  }
}
```

> Notice : Undefined index: psn in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\bumil\app\views\pasien\index.php on line 202
>
> Warning : Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\bumil\app\views\pasien\index.php on line 202
>
> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method Pasien::model()
>   in C:\xampp\htdocs\bumil\app\controllers\Pasien.php:9 Stack trace: #0
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\bumil\app\core\App.php(32): Pasien->index() #1
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\bumil\public\index.php(5): App->__construct() #2
>   {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\bumil\app\controllers\Pasien.php on
>   line 9

Comment: I think you should load `$data['psn']` before you load your view `$this->view('pasien/index');` and have to pass `$data` to loaded view.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Notice: Undefined variable", "Notice: Undefined index", and "Notice: Undefined offset" using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/notice-undefined-variable-notice-undefined-index-and-notice-undefined)

Answer (score 0):

you are using `$data['psn']` befor it loads.

Try the following:

```
<?php

class Pasien extends Controller {

    public function index(){
        $data['judul'] = 'Data Pasien';
        $data['psn'] = $this->model('Data_pasien')->getPasien();
        $this->view('templates/header');
        $this->view('pasien/index',$data);
        $this->view('templates/footer');
    }
}

?>
```